Automate Quotation to share data in sharepoint
How can i ensure that when i save a quotation in Excel the data is automatically saved to SharePoint
I tried Creating a Power App to create a form that will be populating a already made template in excel and use power automate

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

you should store that xls in a Sharepoint Document Library, or in a OneDrive folder (or whatever else, which's modification can trigger a PowerAutomate flow). Make a flow with "When an item or a file is modified" trigger. If your xls file is modified (you write and save it, or autosave) you can set up the flow to copy it to an other SPO folder.

You can try using OneDrive sync.
reference:
https://sharepointmaven.com/how-onedrive-sync-works/
Or I need more details on this issue.
